# Is it possible to add [koalas] tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-request

When posting my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598196/do-i-need-to-install-koalas-on-every-node-of-my-spark-cluster-or-just-on-the-mas), I'd like to add [koalas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/koalas) tag onto the question but the create-tag suggestion was rejected by SO with this error:

> The tag [koalas] is too similar to [koala]

Since [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas) is a totally different framework from Ruby's Koala and there is no [koalas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/koalas) tag yet, would it be possible to add a [koalas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/koalas) tag for Data Engineers/Scientists/Analysts?

Comment: For disambiguation purposes we probably should make the new tag `[pandas-koalas]` and rename the existing one to `[ruby-koala]` or something similar.  Otherwise we'll end up with most new questions for either framework getting tagged with both by lazy askers.

Comment: would it be more suitable with `[spark-koalas]`? since `koalas` is a scaled `pandas` who runs on Apache Spark cluster

Comment: Dan is right: we need to disambiguate this. A moderator can easily rename the existing tag to accomplish that goal, and I'm happy to do that, but I'm not a subject matter expert (or even *familiar* with the subject matter), so I'll need input from folks who know this technology to make sure that we do this correctly.

Comment: @CodyGray Totally agree

Comment: @YuanJI I just took a quick guess from the github page, and will totally defer to experienced users on the best tag name.

Comment: I was going to make a joke about "what's next, a water bear framework?", [but...](http://waterbearlang.com/)